# Cosmos change feed processor and concurrency within a single host

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

After going through Cosmos db documentation I am a bit confused about the change feed processor library.

1. Lease document exists for each physical partition or logical partition?
2. If I only have one host with multiple logical partition and a single physical partition. Will the change feed processor utilize multiple threads for each logical partition. I have cosmos change feed processor library implemented like this.

```
        var changeFeedProcessorInstance = new ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder()
          .options(cfOptions)
          .hostName(hostName)
          .feedContainer(container)
          .leaseContainer(leaseContainer)
          .handleChanges((List<JsonNode> docs) -> {
          for (JsonNode document : docs) {
            // Doing some processing
            }
          })
        .buildChangeFeedProcessor();
        changeFeedProcessorInstance.start()
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
          .doOnSuccess(aVoid -> {
           })
          .subscribe();
```

My assumption is due to Scheduler.elastic a new thread can be utilized per logical partition basis.

Comment: Just to clarify, subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()) makes the event emission and processing pipeline to run in a separate thread from main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Current implementation uses 1 lease document per physical partition.

Parallelization is based off leases. If the lease store has 10 leases, it can be distributed up to 10 hosts because 1 lease can only be owned by a single host at any given point in time (you can use less hosts and leases will be equally distributed).

If your lease store contains 1 lease (because the collection has 1 physical partition), then you can listen for changes in up to 1 host. Adding more hosts will just make the extra sit idle. If the collection grows due to more storage being used, for example, and new physical partitions are dynamically added, new leases will be dynamically added and the extra instances can start to automatically pick them up (if more instances than leases are available). The library does the dynamic distribution of leases over hosts automatically as both dimensions change.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Coming back to my second point, if you have one physical partition (multiple logical partition). Can multiple threads be leveraged within a single host for different logical partition to process faster. 
 Why we are even setting a executer service if that’s not possible I.e  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())

Comment: Following the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor), the processor will spawn one thread per lease, and on that thread, it will perform the [life cycle](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor#processing-life-cycle). If multiple leases exist, then multiple physical partitions will be read in parallel in independent threads, but if a single lease / physical partition exists, only 1 thread will be reading from the change feed. Once you get the results, you can parallelize their processing if you want, at that point is your code.